# Problem during data update in PHP Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

ajax code-

```
...  
xmlhttp.open("GET","voting.php?qid="+qid+", uid="+uid+", type="+type,true);
...
```

is this the correct way to sent three parameters??

html-

```
<td ><img src="images/up.jpeg" style="border:none;" title="Like" onclick="doVote($q_id,$_SESSION['UserId'],up)"></td>
```

when I am clicking on this image ajax script is not working.where should I fire onclick function???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three mistakes:

- The correct notation for multiple GET parameters is separating them by `&` or, if used in HTML source, the correct HTML entity `&amp;`

  ```
  "voting.php?qid="+qid+"&amp;uid="+uid+"&amp;type="+type
  ```
- To output a PHP variable, you need to wrap them around PHP tags:

  ```
  "doVote('<?php echo $q_id; ?>','<?php echo $_SESSION['UserId']; ?>',up)"
  ```
- The third parameter to `doVote()`, "up", needs to be enclosed in quotes if it's meant to be a string:

  ```
   ..., 'up');
  ```

other than that, the onclick event should fire. Check your error console for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The character separating parameters is usually `&` (though you might add/change characters that php will recognize as separators via [arg_separator.input](http://docs.php.net/ini.core#ini.arg-separator.input)).
You also should ensure that the parameters are properly encoded, e.g. via [escape()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp).

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","voting.php?qid="+escape(qid)+"&uid="+escape(uid)+"&type="+escape(type),true);
```